# How to show that demeaning the data in design matrix does not change the hat matrix

Tags: multiple-regression, covariance-matrix, matrix-inverse, projection

When I have a design matrix $$X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{11}  & \ldots & x_{1k}\\
1  &  x_{21} & \ldots & x_{2k}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1  &   x_{n1}  &\ldots & x_{nk}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
how can I show that subtracting the mean from columns $2$ to $k$ does not change the hat matrix given by $$H = X  (X^T  X)^{-1}  X^T \,\,?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you demean the data matrix $X = [1_n,X_2]$, you get the new data matrix 
$$
\tilde{X} = [1_n, \tilde{X}_2],
$$
where $\tilde{X}_2 = [I_n - n^{-1} 1_n 1_n^T]X_2 = DX_2$.

This is all just [inverses of block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion). Hopefully I didn't make a mistake. There's probably a cleaner way to do this.

The (possibly new) hat matrix is 
\begin{align*}
H_2 &= \tilde{X} (\tilde{X}^T \tilde{X})^{-1}\tilde{X}^T \\
&= [1_n, \tilde{X}_2] 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
n & 1_n^T \tilde{X}_2 \\
\tilde{X}_2^T 1_n & \tilde{X}_2^T\tilde{X}_2
\end{array}\right]^{-1}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1_n^T \\
\tilde{X}_2^T
\end{array}
\right] \\
&= [1_n, DX_2] 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
n & 1_n^T DX_2 \\
X_2^TD^T 1_n & X_2^TD^TDX_2
\end{array}\right]^{-1}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1_n^T \\
X_2^TD^T
\end{array}
\right] \\
&= [1_n, DX_2] 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
n & 0 \\
0 & X_2^TDX_2
\end{array}\right]^{-1}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1_n^T \\
X_2^TD^T
\end{array}
\right] \\
&= [1_n, DX_2] 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
n^{-1} & 0 \\
0 & (X_2^TDX_2)^{-1}
\end{array}\right]
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1_n^T \\
X_2^TD^T
\end{array}
\right] \\
&= [n^{-1} 1_n, DX_2(X_2^TDX_2)^{-1}] 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1_n^T \\
X_2^TD^T
\end{array}
\right] \\
&= n^{-1}1_n 1_n^T + DX_2(X_2^TDX_2)^{-1} X_2^TD^T  \\
&= n^{-1}1_n1_n^T + n^{-2}1_n1_n^TX_2[X_2^TDX_2 ]^{-1}X_2^T1_n1_n^T - X_2X_2^TX_2 X_2^T 1_n[X_2^TDX_2]^{-1}1_n^T -n^{-1}1_n1_n^T X_2 [X_2^TDX_2 ]^{-1}X_2^T +X_2[X_2^TDX_2]^{-1}X_2^T \\
&= [n^{-1}1_n + n^{-2}1_n1_n^TX_2[X_2^TDX_2 ]^{-1}X_2^T1_n - X_2X_2^TX_2 X_2^T 1_n[X_2^TDX_2]^{-1}, -n^{-1}1_n1_n^T X_2 [X_2^TDX_2 ]^{-1} +X_2[X_2^TDX_2]^{-1}]
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1_n^T \\
X_2^T
\end{array}
\right] \\
&= [1_n, X_2] \\
&\left[\begin{array}{cc}
n^{-1} + n^{-2}1_n^TX_2[X_2^TDX_2 ]^{-1}X_2^T1_n & -n^{-1}1_n^T X_2 [X_2^TDX_2 ]^{-1} \\
- X_2^TX_2 X_2^T 1_n[X_2^TDX_2]^{-1} & [X_2^TDX_2]^{-1}
\end{array}\right]
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1_n^T \\
X_2^T
\end{array}
\right] \\
&= [1_n, X_2] \\
&\left[\begin{array}{cc}
n^{-1} + n^{-2}1_n^TX_2[X_2^TX_2 - n^{-1}X_2^T1_n1_n^T X_2]^{-1}X_2^T1_n & -n^{-1}1_n^T X_2 [X_2^TX_2 - n^{-1}X_2^T1_n1_n^T X_2]^{-1} \\
- X_2^TX_2 X_2^T 1_n[X_2^TX_2 - n^{-1}X_2^T1_n1_n^T X_2]^{-1} & [X_2^TX_2 - n^{-1}X_2^T1_n1_n^T X_2]^{-1}
\end{array}\right]
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1_n^T \\
X_2^T
\end{array}
\right] \\
&= [1_n, X_2] 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
n & 1_n^T X_2 \\
X_2^T 1_n & X_2^TX_2
\end{array}\right]^{-1}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1_n^T \\
X_2^T
\end{array}
\right] \\
&= X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T
\end{align*}